# Resolve code blocks at runtime (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

first time posting here,

I am writing a dynamic control that I want to pass in something along the lines of the following:

```
HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();  
myLink.NavigateUrl = "/Home.aspx?id=<%= DataBinder.Eval(\"PageId\") %>";  
myLink.Text = "The link";  
myControl.Controls.Add(myLink);
```

I want to be able to resolve the myLink.NavigateUrl at run-time according to the context that myControl puts the control into in the end (this is not a WebControl and therefore adding to the collection of controls doesn't output to page).

Comment: More details please! Can you give a specific example of how your control would be used? Even with your comments for @tster, I don't understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

This question doesn't make any sense to my.  You should know what PageId is at this point so you can just do:

```
HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();  
myLink.NavigateUrl = "/Home.aspx?id=" + PageId;  
myLink.Text = "The link";  
myControl.Controls.Add(myLink);
```

If for some reason you can't do this, can you please provide the code that you are working on that actually needs this.  The example you posted has been too simplified to show us what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't do the above suggestion as I'm writing the myControl, not the consuming code, and therefore myLink could look like anything, with any sort of databinding expression provided.

Comment: Just for some more clarification, I'm building a re-usable control that others will pass a collection of controls into, and specify a data source.   The reusable control will then handle the parsing and rendering of the controls in it's own manner, for example, it will load a state before loading the contents of the data source, and binding the controls, then after loading/binding it will update the state to reflect the loaded data (using an AJAX update panel).

Comment: @Kurt,  all you show of MyControl is it being used and you adding myLink to the control collection.  Please update the question or ask a new one showing what MyControl is suppose to do.  You mention databinding.  Is mycontrol suppose to have repeated items (like the ASP.NET Repeater control)?  If so, you will probably want to look into the ITemplate interface.

Comment: I'm already using the ITemplate, but this doesn't automatically resolve the value of Navigate URL when set in the format specified.  Will re=ask with more info as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

more efficient is:

```
HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
myLink.NavigateUrl = string.Concat("/Home.aspx?id=", PageId);
myLink.Text = "The link";
myControl.Controls.Add(myLink);
```

Comment: Please humor me and explain why that is more efficient when it's just two strings that are concatenated.

Comment: k. its because if you do string concatenation, you create a new string with each + operation. if you use string.format instead, you will create a new string only once. in this example it doesn't matter however, because there is only one string-concat.